# file widget html (in symfony) and name of the file being loaded

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, file-upload

I use the **file** field with symfony to upload an image. When I select an image with this widget, the  name of the image appear in the file field. I would like to be able to get the name display in the widget with javascript so that I could display it in some div.

is this possible? how can I do this? I cannot find the html where the name of the image is displayed.

Here the code I got when having a look at the file widget

```
<input type="file" id="xxx_blogbundle_article_image_file" name="xxx_blogbundle_article[image][file]" required="required" class="input_image_file"  />
```